# Thread exiting with uncaught exception group=0x40015560

Tags: android, pointers, null

Gday guys, im having an issue with an assignment for uni. The idea is that a particle is created when and where the screen is touched. Im getting an uncaught exception when the program attempts to create the particle.

The errors popping out are:

```
05-22 17:39:18.597: I/System.out(1196): screen touched 
05-22 17:39:18.597: I/System.out(1196): about to add point
05-22 17:39:18.597: I/System.out(1196): addpoint called
05-22 17:39:18.606: I/System.out(1196): particle details created
05-22 17:39:18.616: I/System.out(1196): particle created
05-22 17:39:18.616: I/System.out(1196): x:295.61588y:293.3667
05-22 17:39:18.616: D/AndroidRuntime(1196): Shutting down VM
05-22 17:39:18.636: W/dalvikvm(1196): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-22 17:39:18.646: I/System.out(1196): about to draw particles
05-22 17:39:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 17:39:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 17:39:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at au.edu.ballarat.drawing_30103645.DrawingRenderer.addPoint(DrawingRenderer.java:71)
```

The main code : Drawing Activiy is

```
package au.edu.ballarat.drawing_30103645;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class DrawingActivity extends Activity {
    private GLSurfaceView glSurface;
    private DrawingRenderer myRenderer;
    public static Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Call the superclass onCreate
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Instantiate our GLSurfaceView passing it this context
        glSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        // Instantiate our renderer instance so we can use it to draw things
        myRenderer = new DrawingRenderer();
        // Specify we'll use our myRenderer instance to draw things
        glSurface.setRenderer(myRenderer);
        // Display the surface!
        setContentView(glSurface);

        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // When the application is paused, we should call both Activity's
        // and GLSurfaceView's onPause() methods in that order!
        super.onPause(); // Always call the superclass method first!
        glSurface.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // When the application is resumed after pausing, we should call
        // both Activity's and GLSurfaceViews onResume() methods.
        super.onResume();// Always call the superclass method first!
        glSurface.onResume();
}

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("screen touched ");

        int action = event.getAction();
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            DrawingRenderer dr = new DrawingRenderer();
            System.out.println("about to add point");
            dr.addPoint((float)event.getX(), (float)event.getY() );
            System.out.println("action down");
        }   
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){
              System.out.println("action pointer down");
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
              System.out.println("action move");
        }
                return true;
    }}
```

The code for the renderer : DrawingRenderer is

```
package au.edu.ballarat.drawing_30103645;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;




public class DrawingRenderer implements Renderer {
    // Define our array of Particle objects
    private ArrayList<DrawingParticle> particleList;
    DrawingParticle p;

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)

    {

        System.out.println("no error yet");
        particleList = new ArrayList<DrawingParticle>();

    }

    // Method to reset the surface if it flips vertical to horizontal etc.
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        // Reset the width and height of our viewport
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        // Reset the Projection matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        // Set up an orthographic projection
        gl.glOrthof(0, width, 0, height, 1, -1);
        // Reset the ModelView matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        // Specify a "chunky" point size (default is 1.0f)
        gl.glPointSize(3.0f);
    }

    // Method to draw the frame
    @Override
    public synchronized void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // Set the clear colour to red and clear the screen
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



        // Enable the vertex array client state
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        // Draw then update the position of all particles
        System.out.println("about to draw particles");
        for (DrawingParticle p : particleList) {
            System.out.println("about to draw particles");
            p.draw(gl);
            p.update();
        }
        // Disable the vertex array client state before leaving
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }

    public synchronized void addPoint(float xLocation, float yLocation){
        System.out.println("addpoint called");
        DrawingParticle particle = new DrawingParticle(xLocation, yLocation);
        System.out.println("particle created");
        System.out.println("x:"+ xLocation + "y:" + yLocation);
        particleList.add(particle);
        System.out.println(particleList);

    }


}
```

The code for the particle is DrawingParticle:

```
package au.edu.ballarat.drawing_30103645;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import au.edu.ballarat.xylophone_30103645.Utils;

import java.util.Random;

public class DrawingParticle {
    public static final int VERTEX_COUNT = 1; // Each point is 1 vertex
    public static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2; // X and Y co-ords for 2D!
    // Float.SIZE gives us the size of a float in bits (32 bits), divide by 8 //
    // to get size in bytes (4 bytes)!
    public static final int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = VERTEX_COUNT * COORDS_PER_VERTEX
            * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
    private static float vertices[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f }; // Point is at the origin
    private static FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float ySpeed;
    private float GRAVITY = 1.0f;
    private float size;
    private float red, green, blue, alpha;
    private float rotation;
    private int framesToLive;

    // Particle constructor
    public DrawingParticle(float INITIAL_X_LOCATION, float INITIAL_Y_LOCATION) {
        // Allocate memory for our ByteBuffer (1 * 2 * 4 = 8 Bytes)
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFFER_SIZE);
        // Specify byte order in use (little-endian or big-endian)
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        // Specify our vertexBuffer as a FloatBuffer version
        // of our byteBuffer object
        vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        // Put our vertex data in the vertex buffer
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        // Reset our buffer ready for use
        vertexBuffer.flip();
        // Specify a random position for our point
        // Specify random horizontal and vertical speeds for our point


        red = Utils.randRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
        green = Utils.randRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
        blue = Utils.randRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
        alpha = Utils.randRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
        ySpeed = Utils.randRange(1.0f, 6.0f);
        x = INITIAL_X_LOCATION;
        y = INITIAL_Y_LOCATION;
        size = Utils.randRange(1.0f, 6.0f);
        rotation = 0.0f;
        System.out.println("particle details created");
    }

    synchronized void draw(GL10 gl) {
        System.out.println("Draw called");
        // Reset the ModelView matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        // Specify our vertexes
        gl.glColor4f(green, red, blue, alpha);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, DrawingParticle.vertexBuffer);
        gl.glPointSize(size);
        // Translate (i.e. move horizontally and vertically) to the
        // position of the particle
        gl.glTranslatef(x,y, 0.0f);
        // And finally draw the particle as a point!
        // Params: Primitive type, start location of vertexBuffer, end
        // location of vertexBuffe
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, DrawingParticle.VERTEX_COUNT);
    }

    public synchronized void update() {
        // Move the particle by its component speeds

        y += ySpeed;
        ySpeed -= GRAVITY;

        // reduce the alpha
        if (alpha > 0.1f){
            alpha = alpha - 0.1f;
        }
        framesToLive = framesToLive - 1;
        size = size + 0.3f;
        rotation = rotation + 1;

    }
}
```

I understand that it could be fixed with something as simple as a try/ catch block but i am not sure where one would be placed. Its for a school assignment so i have no choice but to try finish it.

Thanks for any help a user on here can provide.

Comment: what's the code in `DrawingRenderer` on line 71?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`particleList` is `null` when you call `addPoint` because in the `onTouchEvent` of your `DrawingActivity`, you call it on a new instance of the `DrawingRenderer`, for which the `onSurfaceCreated` would not be called.

I think in the `onTouchEvent`, you should be calling `mRenderer.addPoint` instead of on the newly instantiated `dr`.

Comment: im not sure what your referring to when you say mRenderer, but if i try call DrawingRenderer.addpoint it creates a nonstatic reference error

Comment: Do you realize that you have defined an instance variable `private DrawingRenderer myRenderer;` in your `DrawingActivity`?

Comment: at the time no, thanks for pointing that out. Now i just gotta get the damn particles drawing.